# How to correctly clear list in java

Tags: java, list

Lets say I have a list like this:

```
private LinkedList<String> messages = new LinkedList<String>();
```

When my method gets invoked for the first time there some strings added to this list. And I have also another method in which I need to clear this list from previously added values. To clear it I can use:

```
messages.clear();
```

This will remove all the elements from the list. Also I can create a new instance like this:

```
messages = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Which way is more proper to clear the list?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between them? It depends which one you want.

Comment: @SLaks this is admittedly an implementation detail that achieves the same goal, making messages empty.

Comment: @assylias: No; it depends whether he has exposed that instance elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It clearly depends upon your need.

If you want to keep reference to your list object instance (as an example if that clear method is called inside a method in which the `messages` is a parameter, then the call to `.clear()` is the best solution.

On the other hand, if the list you want to clear is a member field (or a local variable in a method) of the object the current method is a member of, then you can call `new LinkedList<String>();` without any trouble.

Notice that, to avoid the first (which I tend to disapprove), i usuall always return obejcts I modify as results from methods modifying them.

Answer (score 3):

```
messages.clear();
```

Will actually clear the list, `messages = new LinkedList<String>();` will just set `messages` as referencing a new list instance, so you could argue the first way is more "correct" to clear the list instance.

Answer (score 3):

Say you have a list that is referenced by two variables, a and b. Like this (they don't have to be as close to eachother as this, they might even be in different files..):

```
final List<String> a = new LinkedList<String>();
final List<String> b = a;
```

Now, there is a big difference between

```
a.clear();
```

which will make both a and b reference the same, empty list, and

```
a = new LinkedList<String>();
```

which will make 'a' reference a new, empty list, and 'b' the old, populated list. (So they do not reference the same list).

Since you probably want them to reference the same list, a.clear() is preferred, since you won't get any surprises when your looking at the list referenced by b (which you might believe to be empty, but turns out to be populated if you use the new-approach).

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the first approach i.e. `messages.clear();` as it clear the elements but the List is not destroyed and recreated. All elements are removed as desired.

**One side effect** is there though: It iterates your list and removes one item at a time so if the list is huge then it's an unnecessary overhead.

```
    for (Node<E> x = first; x != null; ) {
        Node<E> next = x.next;
        x.item = null;
        x.next = null;
        x.prev = null;
        x = next;
    }
    first = last = null;
    size = 0;
    modCount++;
```

Same way **second approach has also one side effect**: If you are using the object reference of you r list somewhere else in your program, that needs to handled properly otherwise you could get some unwanted surprises e.g. if you added your list to some other object/variable, then first approach will clear that elements from every place where it was referenced while second will not.

**Summary**: Both the approach outcomes are different in low level nature; though they seem to to serve your high level requirement (clearing the list). **Decide carefully based on your low level requirements.**

Answer (score 1):

They are almost similar, but I would say `messages.clear()` is more flexible.

The second approach is simple and much used, but the problem where you have `final` modifier on your list you can not clear it that way.

Answer (score 1):

```
messages.clear();
```

is more efficient. For more safety you can ask if this list is not empty befor

Comment: "*For more safety*" what do you mean? if the list is empty, `clear()` will do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Personnaly I prefere to use [LinkedList#clear](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#clear%28%29) because it is more clearly to understand during reading the code what you are doing.

But the `new LinkedList<String>();` will work fine as well. So it's up to you what to use!

Answer (score 0):

the first one is preferable. the second one makes some extra burden on the garbage collector. but the first one not.

Comment: Some extra burden? No it doesn't. The GC runs regardless of what you do. And even when it runs and has some stuff to clean up, you don't really know what kind of an impact this has on it. It all depends on what GC strategy will be applied.

Comment: well when you dont have some orphan reference the GC don't needs to check them regardless whatever strategy is applied in the GC. Am i right?